# Why is sessions reset in my rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, session, session-variables

I has some features which settings I save in session. But after 1 times reload they reset and session values doesn't exist there.

First load I get session

```
{"session_id"=>"xxx"}
```

After save value I get

```
{"session_id"=>"xxx", "value"=>"100"}
```

And when I reload my page again I get reset session

```
{"session_id"=>"xxx"}
```

Why it can be?

Comment: How are you manipulating the session?

Comment: add - `session[:value] = 100` and remove - `session[:value] = nil`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for every one, I find problem but I can't explain it.
Later I remove row from js file `app/assets/javascripts/application.js`

```
//= require jquery_ujs
```

When I put it back, it's stop reset session values.

Comment: Cool! Didn't know jquery_ujs handles the CSRF token (which is logical btw). Don't forget to accept your own answer, so that others could know what worked for you.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you're not passing the CSRF token in one of your (probably AJAX) requests. If rails receives invalid CSRF token - it resets the session.

Check out: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#cross-site-request-forgery-csrf

Update: Vidya is right. You may also want to add the following code to your ApplicationController - to set the XSRF token for AJAX calls

```
after_filter  :set_csrf_cookie

def set_csrf_cookie
   cookies['XSRF-TOKEN'] = form_authenticity_token if protect_against_forgery?
end
```

Comment: I have `<%= csrf_meta_tags %>` in head tag. Does you mean that?

Answer (score 1):

Igor is exactly right. If that happens to be the case in your application, do something like this:

```
$(document).ajaxSend((event, jqxhr, settings) ->
    jqxhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRF-Token", $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'))
    jqxhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRF-Param", $('meta[name="csrf-param"]').attr('content'))
    return
)
```

Now that's CoffeScript, and that assumes you are using JQuery. Regardless, the point is you need to send the CSRF metadata along for the ride with your Ajax requests.